# How can I disable the Wi-fi radio permanently to save power?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager

I can disable it with

```
sudo nmcli radio wifi off
```

but it turns back on after a reboot. The only thread I could find was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24171/how-can-i-keep-a-wireless-cards-radio-powered-off-by-default), but it only applies to Ubuntu, and I'm using Arch Linux.

My laptop has a physical switch, but it doesn't actually disable the Wi-fi card. It just asks the OS to turn off Wi-fi, but it turns back on after a reboot.

To be clear: I don't just want to turn off Wi-fi and stop NetworkManager from connecting to networks. I want to disable the radio entirely and permanently, so it doesn't consume any power ever.

Edit: I would also like to easily enable the wireless card as needed.

Comment: Refer to `man rfkill`

Comment: You might be able to remove your wi-fi card entirely...

Comment: Have a look in the BIOS/UEFI, some laptops can disable wifi & bluetooth from there.

Comment: @Stephen according to the [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03765776) (page 47) for my HP Probook 250 G0, I can remove it. I didn't think it was doable for a laptop, especially not a low-end one like mine. Thanks!

Comment: @Krackout there's no guarantee that the UEFI option will turn off power for the card. It might just disable communication, in which case the card will still be passively powered.

Comment: @Artem I've found that, with `rfkill block <interface>`, the interface stays block after a reboot. I've also found, through some research, that blocking an interface with rfkill turns its radio off completely. I prefer this over removing the wireless card, as I can easily unblock the interface when I need to use it.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu with NetworkManager on three laptops (different hardware). On the first one, turning WiFi off in NetworkManager also disables the hardware; on the second one it does not disable the hardware immediately, but does refrain from enabling it on reboot; on the third one it only puts down the interface, but does not affect the hardware at all. Sometimes rfkill helps, sometimes it does not. So it varies wildly depending on the hardware and kernel involved.

Comment: @Hermann how do you test whether the hardware is off?

Comment: @GLIBG10B There is a "power on" led on each of them. The power supply reports reduced current while the system is idle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rfkill block ID|type
```

Might be what you're looking for. Run without any parameters to find out what devices you've got.

Answer (score 6):

Many laptops use Mini PCI-Express cards or M.2 wireless cards for wi-fi, and these can be removed (see [this How-To Geek article on upgrading wireless cards](https://www.howtogeek.com/346854/how-to-upgrade-or-replace-your-pcs-wireless-card/) for example). In such cases, the best way to ensure that the wi-fi adapter doesn’t consume any power is to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You can unload the Wi-Fi module using the `modprobe` command then create a blacklist file to prevent the kernel module from loading.

```
sudo modprobe -rv module_name
echo "blacklist module_name" |sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

To enable it again you can load the module driver and remove it from the blacklist file:

```
sudo modprobe -v module_name
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

To get the kernel module for the PCI Wi-Fi card:

```
lspci -knn | grep -i net -A2 | awk -F':' '/Kernel modules/{print $2}'
```

Unloading the kernel module reduce the power consumption. e,g: When the system is resumed or suspended  the kernel calls on drivers to store their states and then unloads them to reduce the power consumption.

Thinkwiki : [How to reduce power consumption](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_reduce_power_consumption)

> Unload drivers for unused devices (ie. USB 1.1, Yenta/PCMCIA, Wireless, IRDA, Bluetooth, ...)

Comment: According to [this thread on forums.linuxmint.com](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=333998), disabling the kernel modules for onboard devices doesn't necessarily reduce power consumption. It probably depends on the device and the motherboard's firmware.

Comment: @GLIBG10B I have added some explanations.

Comment: @GAD3R if you read that page further down, it explains that reducing power consumption of wi-fi module can require *loading* the module but with appropriate options to prevent it from scanning aggressively. There are many devices which use more power when they’re not controlled by a driver.

Comment: You are overriding /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. That might not be a good idea per se. One might want tee -a (for append).